# You, the employer, "contribute the most" or "contributes the most"?

Tags: verb-agreement, appositives, grammatical-person

1. You, the employer, **contribute** the most.
2. You, the employer, **contributes** the most.

Which one would be correct?

Comment: This is very basic. Please check a grammar book for simple present tense verb conjugation.

Comment: sorry updated the question

Comment: It may be basic, but appositives are usually not covered. The first one is the correct one.

Comment: And languages differ in how they handle them, so that it doesn't fall out of basic universal principles such as subject-verb agreement.

Answer (score 8):

The part of the sentence offset by commas (the employer) is called an [appositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition). It gives information about the word "you", but does not take its place as the subject. The word "you" is still the one with which the verb must agree. Hence, the correct choice is the first sentence,

> You, the employer, contribute the most.